How to prove an infinite, bounded, subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R} $ contains a sequence converging to the supremum of $A$ .
There was a similar question, Bolzano-Weierstrass proof correction, but the resolution uses concepts I have not studied such as accumulation points.
I would like to know how to prove that in every infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded there exists a growing convergent subsequence such that it's limit is the supremum of the subset, using only that a bounded strictly growing sequence converges and  definitions of sequence and supremum.
I tried doing something like the following:
*A the infinite subset
u=sup(A)$\implies u\geq a;\forall a \in A $  and $u-\epsilon \leq a_i, \forall \epsilon > 0  $ and for some element in A.
The sequence X has the property that $x_{n+1} > x_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
From these, $u \geq x_{n+1} > x_n , \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a_i +\epsilon -x_n > u-x_n \geq x_{n+1} -x_n > 0$ since $a_i +\epsilon -x_n >0 $,$a_i +\epsilon -x_n > u-x_n \geq x_{n+1} -x_n > 0> x_n-\epsilon -a_i$
Here is what I'm not sure. Could we call a new  $\epsilon_1 = a_i+\epsilon -x_n$ ? Then use the triangle inequality to say $$\epsilon_1> u-x_n >-\epsilon_1 \implies \epsilon_1 > |u-x_n|$$

the quantification and naming of your variables is unclear to me. It is easier in my opinion to explicitly construct the sequence. I am not sure what you are doing exactly.

Choose $x_0\in A$ and $y_0$ some upper bound of $A$. Let $c=\frac{x_0+y_0}{2}$. If $c$ is an upper bound of $A$ let $x_1:=x_0$ and $y_1:=c$. Otherwise there is some $A\ni x_1\geq c$. In this case let $y_1:=y_0$. Continuing this construction it is easy to verify that the limit of the sequence $(x_n) $ equals the supremum of $A$.
Edit: To be more explicit, it is easy to see that the sequence $(x_n)$ is increasing and that
$(y_n)$ is decreasing. Moreover by construction $x_n\leq y_n$ and $0\leq y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}\leq\frac{y_n-x_n}{2}$. Thus both sequences converge to a common limit $\xi$. Since all $y_n$ are upper bounds of $A$ the limit $\xi$ is also an upper bound of $A$.
Finally we may conclude that $\xi$ is the lowest  upper bound of $A$: Let $b<\xi$. Then, since $\xi$ is the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$, the $x_n$ must be larger than $b$ for all sufficiently lange $n$. Since by consruction all $x_n$ are contained in $A$ we get that $\xi$ is indeed the supremum of $A$.

However, it need not be strictly monotone, as was required by the OP. Indeed, this is not always possible. Perhaps worth mentioning.

I considered the task as mentioned in the title.

Yes, sorry, the problem asks for a growing, not strictly growing

I don't understand how to prove that sequence's limit is the supremum. I understand that every iteration x and y approach the supremum but I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

See my edit of the answer.

I'm sorry but I don't understand why $\frac{y_n-x_n}{2} \geq y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}$ is true  and how that implies they have the same limit.

If $x_{n+1}=x_n$ (and $y_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}=:c$) we have $y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}-x_n=\frac{y_n-x_n}{2}$. Otherwise $x_{n+1}\geq c$ (and $y_{n+1}=y_n$) implying  $y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}=y_n-x_{n+1}\leq y_n-c=\frac{y_n-x_n}{2}$.

First, not every such set has a strictly monotone increasing such sequence. For example, $(0,1) \cup \{2\}$. Thus, let us drop that requirement.
You seem to be trying to show that every monotone increasing sequence converges to the supremum. This is not the case. You must actually build the sequence $(x_n)$. Here is what I would do:
Let $u=\sup A$. Consider a function $a: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$a(y) = \mbox{choice from} \left[\frac{u+y}{2},u\right]\cap A$$
and since the RHS is non empty by definition of supremum, this is a function by the Axiom of Choice.
Choose $x_1 \in A$. Define $(x_n)$ recursively by the following rule:
$$x_n = a(x_{n-1})$$
Can you prove this has the right properties? This type of construction is common in analysis, it would be good to get comfortable with it.
An aside, if instead of $A$ being infinite, you require that $A$ has no maximum, you do indeed get a strictly monotone sequence by this construction.
Finally, this is the same sequence $(x_n)$ (obviously only up to choice function) you get by applying @JensSchwaiger ’s construction with $y_0=\sup A$.
